# How to get an emulator with play store for an xxxhdpi device?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play, vhd

How to get android emulator with play store for xxxhdpi device?
Currently it is only available for 2 resolutions[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just press on the "clone device" button, and you will be able to set the resolution for the display size (hence you get your density) :

[image]

[image]

Comment: it is not changing

Comment: @Midhilaj Have you opened the emulator after this, and got to see the density is incorrect? If so, you should file a bug, because that's not an expected behavior: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues